# Using turbolinks with Rails select & jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a `select` tag that displays a dropdown in my Rails application. I want to be able to use jQuery to show and hide a div depending on the selection of that select element. I can not get it to work and I believe it is due to turbolinks not playing nice with jQuery. When I go to EDIT an existing record that has the dropdown selected to the correct option ('Cheque'), the field IS shown as I would like. But when I create a new record, and select the option from the dropdown, it does not show the hidden div as I would like.

I tried to add the data attribute for turbo links to false but it does not work.

```
<%= f.select :payment_method, @payment_methods, {:include_blank => true}, { :class => 'form-control', :id => 'payment-method', 'data-turbolinks'=>'false' } %>
```

And of course, all my jQuery is wrapped in:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  function vanish(x) {
    x.css('display', 'none');
  }
  function reappear(x) {
    x.css('display', 'block');
  }

  // for showing cheque number field if payment method is cheque
  vanish($('#cheque-number-section'));

  if ($("#payment-method option:selected").text() == "Cheque") {
    reappear($('#cheque-number-section'));
  } else {
    vanish($('#cheque-number-section'));
  }

});
```

Comment: I believe you should try adding an event to look for on change, then evaluate your if statement as well - else your javascript is only evaluated once on load - fyi, `turbolinks:load` covers both turbolinks and the ready event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dstull's comment got me to find the answer. Had to check for the change of the select element!

```
$("#payment-method").on('change', function() {
    if($("#payment-method option:selected").text() == "Cheque"){
        reappear($('#cheque-number-section'));
    } else {
        vanish($('#cheque-number-section'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function(){
 // wrap your code here
})
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I had already tried wrapping my code inside a document.ready function call inside of the `turbolinks:load`.

Comment: Just a heads up, I was using this code for a few hours because I forgot to remove the `ready`, and all of my calls to `console.log` were being executed twice...